# Change the content of “:before” element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following css:

```
.example:before {
    content: " $ ";
    margin-left: 4px;
    color: #666;
 }
```

I'd like to change the 'content' using jQuery. What selector to I use to access this element?

Comment: Your question title shows something **impossible** but your question content shows that it's possible because it's just **to change the content** not **style the :before via jQuery**. It's so confusing. It's better to re-edit the tittle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't directly access `:before` or `:after` with Javascript at all.  The only way I know to modify them at runtime is to use an attribute, but that sort of defeats the purpose of having css add content in the first place....

**HTML**

```
<div class="example" title=" $ ">Something in the div</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.example:before {
    content: attr(title);    /* use the value of the title attribute */
    margin-left: 4px;
    color: #666;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".example").attr("title", " £ ");
```

**[working jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/7WS6Z/)**

Like I said, this sort of negates the whole point of the `:before` selector and you may as well simply prepend something using Javascript anyway.